# Azure DevOps publish zip remove hidden folder

Tags: azure-devops, dotnet-publish

I'm configuring an azure devops pipeline and want to zip the package for the publish.
When I choose to zip, a directory that I have in the code (/wwwroot/.well-known) is not included in the zip.

Is there an option that exclude hidden folders?

[image: Configuration of the publish pipeline]

Comment: Are you looking to include the `.well-known` directory while publishing your dotnet project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the Azure DevOps task for running .NET commands has the option to include/exclude files while publishing. You can however configure that in your `.csproj` file.

Please refer the documentation on [CopyToPublishDirectory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#copytopublishdirectory).

I have tried the following and I was able to include a directory called `.well-known` which was created in my `wwwroot` folder

```
$ dotnet new webapp -o aspnetcoreapp
$ cd aspnetcoreapp
$ mkdir wwwroot/.well-known && touch wwwroot/.well-known/some-file
```

Add this to your `.csproj` file to include the `.well-known` directory

```
<ItemGroup>                                                                                                                                                           
    <Content  Include="wwwroot/.well-known/*" CopyToOutputDirectory="PreserveNewest" CopyToPublishDirectory="PreserveNewest" />                                         
</ItemGroup>
```

Publish your project

```
$ dotnet publish
$ ls -la bin/Debug/net6.0/publish/wwwroot
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the publish works well and if I don't zip afterwise, I have the file delpoyed.
The issue I am encountering is that when I zip it, it disappears...

Comment: At the end of the day, I implemented your solution, my issue was that in one case it was publishing using dotnet 6 and in the other case dotnet 7. That caused the difference of the include !